# Using VBA to put a chart series on the secondary X axis

Tags: vba, excel

I have a line chart to which I'm attempting to add, via VBA, a horizontal line at a given Y value. I'm following [this guide](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/AddLineHorzSeries.html), which suggests adding a line to an existing chart and then changing its type to scatter, which causes Excel to put the series on the secondary X axis automatically. It can then be formatted further.

My problem is that when doing this with VBA I don't understand how to switch a line onto the secondary X axis. By default all new lines will go on the primary X axis.

For example, suppose `chrt` is a Chart object:

```
' Enable secondary X axis (I think)
chrt.HasAxis(XlAxisType.xlCategory, XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary) = True

Dim se As Series
Set se = chrt.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
se.ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers

' Add a line at Y = 0
se.xValues = Array(0, 1)
se.values = Array(0, 0)
```

Now, how to get `se` onto the secondary X axis?

Comment: what version of Excel are you using? Can you try the following answer and comment. The code below is only to make the line to have secondary axis. So I assume everything else is fine in your code which is not shown here..

Comment: You have to assign at least one series to AxisGroup xlSecondary. Excel may automatically add secondary axis or axes; generally it does add the secondary value axis and often not the secondary category axis.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I followed this [link for Excel 2003](http://www.andypope.info/tips/tip008.htm) and recorded a macro. Please note that for Excel 2007 charts have such a unfortunate cases with recording macros. But you get lucky in Excel 2010 again. So watch out for your version if you are going to do it based on a macro and then copy the code...

Change sheet and chart name according to yours.

```
With Sheets(3).ChartObjects("Chart 1")
     .SeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = xlSecondary
     .HasAxis(xlCategory, xlPrimary) = True
     .HasAxis(xlCategory, xlSecondary) = True
     .HasAxis(xlValue, xlPrimary) = True
     .HasAxis(xlValue, xlSecondary) = True
     .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).CategoryType = xlAutomatic
     .Axes(xlCategory, xlSecondary).CategoryType = xlAutomatic
  End With
```

Comment: Thanks @bonCodigo, that works on Excel 2010. I experimented with the code a bit, and it looks like the key part is to first create the series, set AxisGroup = 2, and THEN run HasAxis(XlAxisType.xlCategory, XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary) = True.

Comment: @Abiel I am glad you got it worked :D thanks for sharing your version. It helps me as well. Preciely you got it in your comment.

Comment: +1 thanks for picking up my dropped ball (I deleted my prior suggestion)

Comment: @brettdj Thanks :) didn't know you had one here - when I came in none was there, so I shot ;)

Comment: @bonCodigo when you get to 10K you will be able to see deleted posts :)

Comment: Thanks again for everyone's help. As I went through the problem further I ran into a more complicated use case, leading to a follow-up question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313203/using-vba-to-plot-a-horizontal-line-against-primary-y-axis-while-retaining-secon

Comment: @JonPeltier I salute your `charts` :) great to see you here.