# Plot series on secondary axis

Tags: excel, vba, axis, excel-charts

I have this code which is ok in excel 2016 on a mac.

```
Sub electricitychart()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cht As ChartObject                         
    If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete
    End If
    Range("e5").Activate
    lrow = Range("a3").End(xlDown).row
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("a2:e" & lrow)
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=ActiveCell.Left, _
        Width:=700, Top:=ActiveCell.Top, Height:=450)
    cht.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
    cht.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    cht.Chart.HasTitle = True
    cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Electricity costs and usage"
    cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Font.Name = "arial"
    cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Font.Size = 14
    cht.Chart.ChartTitle.Font.Bold = msoTrue
    cht.Chart.SeriesCollection("KWh").Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(53, 91, 183)
    cht.Chart.SeriesCollection("Total cost $").Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    cht.Chart.SeriesCollection("Elect cost $").Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(91, 25, 143)
    cht.Chart.SeriesCollection("Supply $").Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(253, 181, 10)
End Sub
```

I would like to plot the series "Total cost $", "Elect cost $" and "Supply $" on the secondary axis, change the format of the secondary axis to 0 decimal places and add a title to the secondary axis.
I have looked at numerous examples elsewhere but cannot seem to get the syntax right. Could someone help with this particular example please?

Tried to make the changes in on "with...end with" block but with no success

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302560/using-vba-to-put-a-chart-series-on-the-secondary-x-axis